# How can I create a graph from dataframe columns where nodes = (user_id, friend_id) and edge = (IsFriend, value is 0/1)

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

| User_ID | Friend_Id | IsFriend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |

nodes = (user_id, friend_id)
Connect nodes through egde = If: IsFriend = 1

Comment: Hi Mayank, pardon me for dropping in like this.  Just wanted to let you know it's not always necessary to delete a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888737/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-void-to-list-of-class-type) that is closed.  You can always make it better by following the instructions on the closure header.  Doing so will allow others to vote for it to be _re-opened_.  So it's not always the end of the world.  Remember, we are all here to help each other.  :) Have a great day!

Comment: Hello Micky, you have been very helpful. I tried for so long to modify the question and add more details but for some reason, I am not able to modify the code.

Comment: Not to worry, you can always post a _new_ question with the changes that you wanted. :)

Comment: I tried but still I am not able to add the code. While posting it keep saying "Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code".

Comment: Ah ok, in your post where you have the code listing, you need to add some sort of description about your problem, any error you might be getting, things you have tried, that sort of thing.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70886713/585968)

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot, @MickyD. Appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want edges to be present only if `IsFriend == 1` then:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'UserID': [1, 2, 3],
                             'Friend_Id': [2, 3, 4],
                             'IsFriend': [1, 1, 0]})

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(pd.concat([df.UserID, df.Friend_Id], axis=0))
G.add_edges_from(np.array(df[df.IsFriend.eq(1)][['UserID', 'Friend_Id']]))
```

If you're okay with `IsFriend == 0` implying an edge but with zero weight, then you can simply do:

```
H = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 
                            source='UserID', 
                            target='Friend_Id', 
                            create_using=nx.Graph, 
                            edge_attr='IsFriend')
```