# How do I get the "await using" syntax correct?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, iasyncdisposable

I have the following synchronous code, which works fine:

```
    private void GenerateExportOutput()
    {
        using StreamWriter writer = new(Coordinator.OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt");

        if (this.WikiPagesToExport.IsEmpty)
        {
            return;
        }

        var wanted = new SortedDictionary<string, WikiPage>(this.WikiPagesToExport, StringComparer.Ordinal);
        foreach (var title in wanted.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(title);
        }
    }
```

I want to change it to be asynchronous. So:

```
    private async Task GenerateExportOutputAsync()
    {
        using StreamWriter writer = new(Coordinator.OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt");

        if (this.WikiPagesToExport.IsEmpty)
        {
            return;
        }

        var wanted = new SortedDictionary<string, WikiPage>(this.WikiPagesToExport, StringComparer.Ordinal);
        foreach (var title in wanted.Keys)
        {
            await writer.WriteLineAsync(title).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        await writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

Which compiles. But one of the analyzers I use ([Meziantou.Analyzer](https://github.com/meziantou/Meziantou.Analyzer)) now suggests that I "prefer using 'await using'". I've never used await using (though I've tried several times in the past and have always run into the same problems I'm running into now). But I would like to use it, so:

```
        await using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Now it no longer compiles: `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredAsyncDisposable' to 'System.IO.StreamWriter'`. OK, fine, so I change it to use `var` instead:

```
        await using var writer = new StreamWriter(OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Which gets it past the CS0029, but now the later code doesn't compile: `Error CS1061 'ConfiguredAsyncDisposable' does not contain a definition for 'WriteLineAsync'` (and a similar one for `FlushAsync`. Soooo... maybe cast it?

```
            await ((StreamWriter)writer).WriteLineAsync(title).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Nope: `Error CS0030 Cannot convert type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredAsyncDisposable' to 'System.IO.StreamWriter'`

I've googled a bunch and read a bunch, both now and several times in the past, but I just have been completely unable to figure out how to use this "await using" thing. How can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233779-using-await-using-iasyncdisposable-with-configureawait

Comment: @madreflection, thank you!

Comment: One more for good measure... https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2661

Comment: `using var writer = new StreamWriter("...");` then on the next line:
            `await writer.WriteLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`

Comment: Side note: `ConfigureAwait(false)` only really needs to be used if you're developing a third-party library. If this project is a web or desktop application, you don't need it. Some people recommend you always use it, but that causes more trouble than any good (if any). I never use it.

Comment: @Charles: That might work (as in not thrown an exception), but it won't call `IAsyncDisposable.Dispose` on the stream object. It'll use `IDisposable.Dispose` instead.

Comment: @madreflection so first line `await using var writer = new StreamWriter("...") ;`

Comment: @Charles: Sure, except you can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on that directly, which is the crux of this question. The pages I linked show `await using (_variable_.ConfigureAwait(false))` *after* assigning something to `_variable_`. The variable has the right type, while `await using` separately captures the configured awaitable used for async disposal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `await using` syntax currently ([C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10)) leaves a lot to be desired, regarding its support for configuring the awaiting of `IAsyncDisposable`s. The best we can do is this:

```
private async Task GenerateExportOutputAsync()
{
    StreamWriter writer = new(Coordinator.OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt");
    await using (writer.ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

...which is not really much more compact than not using the `await using` syntax at all:

```
private async Task GenerateExportOutputAsync()
{
    StreamWriter writer = new(Coordinator.OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt");
    try
    {
        //...
    }
    finally { await writer.DisposeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); }
}
```

Related GitHub issue: [Using ConfigureAwait in "await using" declaration](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2661).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in two lines:

```
private async Task GenerateExportOutputAsync()
{
    StreamWriter writer = new(Coordinator.OutputDirectory + @"\export.txt");
    await using var _ = writer.ConfigureAwait(false);
    //...
}
```

Comment: This creates a variable with the name `_`. It's not a [discard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards). If you try to nest another `await using var _ =` in the same method, you'll get a compile error because of the doubly declared variable `_`.